# jQuery show & hide not working on iPad or iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

All the functions in the following code work fine on desktop browsers, but on iPad and iPhone the top 2 functions work but the 3rd (starting **$('input#pagebreakhomeNext').click(function () {** ) doesn't work at all.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('div.rsform-block-pagebreak input').click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop($('div.calculator').offset().top);
    return false;
    });
    $('a#pagebreaksubmitNext').click(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop($('div.calculator').offset().top);
    return false;
    });
    $('input#pagebreakhomeNext').click(function () {
        if ($('input#postcode').val() != "") {
            var code = $('input#postcode').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: “URL HIDDEN”,
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'code='+code,
        async: false,
        success: function(json) {
            if((json.found) && $('input.benefits:checked').val() != "I do not get any of these benefits" && $('input.ownership:checked').val() == "Yes" && $('input.insulation:checked').val() == "Yes" && $('input.walls:checked').val() == "Solid Walls" && $('input.houseage:checked').val() == "Between 1930 and 1976") { $('div.rsform-block-success').hide(); $('div.rsform-block-failure').show(); }         
            else if((json.found) && $('input.benefits:checked').val() != "I do not get any of these benefits" && $('input.ownership:checked').val() == "Yes" && $('input.insulation:checked').val() == "Yes" && $('input.walls:checked').val() == "Solid Walls" && $('input.houseage:checked').val() == "After 1980") { $('div.rsform-block-success').hide(); $('div.rsform-block-failure').show(); }
            else { $('div.rsform-block-success').show(); $('div.rsform-block-failure').hide(); }
        }
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Please can somebody help?!

Answer (score 1):

use the "touchstart" event instead the "click".

Comment: This worked for me, i replaced 
 $(document).on('click', '#featuredPlayer', function () {
          });

with  $(document).on('touchstart', '#featuredPlayer', function () {
            
          });